# Cassandra data query problems with PDI 5.3

Tags: cassandra, pdi

I have a Cassandra installation which contains a table with no more then 110k records.

I'm getting quite a lot of troubles querying the data using PDI 5.3 (the latest version). I am constantly getting out of memory on Cassandra side.

Granted that the server I have Cassandra installed is not the greatest, 4Gb RAM and only 2 cores, I would still expect to perform this simple task without issues.

In cassandra `/conf/cassandra-env.sh`, I've configured:

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="200M"
```

and now the maximum number of rows I can query is 80k.
The documentation suggests to set MAX_HEAP_SIZE to 1/4th of the machines RAM. But for me that meant 1G and only about 20k rows to query.

I am able to tell how many rows I can query by limiting the select, with the `limit` keyword, inside the `Cassandra input` step in PDI.

Are there any other parameters I can tweak to get better performance? This is a development server, on production I'll be expecting queries with 1mil+ rows.

Server on which Cassandra is installed: **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)**

Cassandra version: **apache-cassandra-2.1.2**

Edit: *versions updated.*

Comment: What version of C* are you running? Also why are you querying such large volumes of data? Selecting 1M rows is a great way to oom, at this stage you should be paginating. We do need error logs however, ill post an answer but its more of a suggestion than a resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sacrifice IO for Memory (since memory is killing you):

- lower key / row caches if they are enabled (key cache is on by default)
- if you carry out lots of deletes you can lower gc_grace_seconds to remove tombstones quicker (assuming you many range scans which you do if you fetch 80k rows, this can help)

Some other ideas:

- **Paginate** (Select 0-10k of 80k, then 10-20k etc.
- Check sizes of memtables, if they are too large lower them.
- Use tracing to verify what you are retrieving ([tombstones can cause lots of overhead](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html))

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/4TJjpGTpsXk) suggests lowering the commit_log size, but the commit log was heavily revamped and moved offheap in 2.1 and shouldn't be such an issue anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am querying large amount of data because I am having lots of data. I'll actually need about 1mil records on each run. I know that paginating should be the solution, but PDI, the Pentaho ETL tool I am using to query the data doesn't support it (as far as I can see). I am in contact with their support right now to see how to handle large data querying. I'll post here an update if and when I solve this issue. I'll update the versions in the question.

Comment: Take a look at the [twissandra](https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra) example application that has manual pagination implemented. It is on a timeline however there are ways around the datamodel that allow you to patinate manually.